# Очистить State на nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, typescript, nuxt.js, vue3, usestate

в `./conposables/state.ts` добавленна такая функция

```
export const datepicker =  () => useState("datepicker",()=> (new Date()).toISOString().split('T')[0]);
```

Как эту штуку очищать? например, при выходе из аккаунта не перезагружая страницы?